I have a persisting issue with (Error: '\U' used without hex digits ) coming up every time I open R terminal. Has anyone seen this before?
I am having to use R the outdated version 3.6.3 as the package I am working with has dependencies which are only available in older versions of R. However I am also getting this issue in R 4.4.1 so not sure if this is relevant.
Whenever I start either version of R it comes up with this error.
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting "'C:\U"

In R 4.4.1 I am able to install packages as normal, however in R 3.6.3 I get the same error.
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting "'C:\U"
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status

I checked my working directory, and library directory but both seem to follow the correct format. I am not sure where the "C:\U" part is coming from so can not update it.
> .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/lena1/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.6"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.3/library"

> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/lena1/OneDrive/Documents"

I also checked the .Rprofile file for any single backslashes but did not find any.

A likely guess is that you have an Rprofile file (or maybe some environment settings) that use Windows style paths, e.g. "C:\Users\lena1...".  See ?Startup for the places to look.

... in which case, you can solve the problem by escapiong the backslashes with backslashes: "C:\\Users\\lena1\\...".
